# How to get all input tag name then get its id and add some text every input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get all `input` tag name then get its id and add some text every input tags?

For example the inputs are:

```js
var inputs, index;

inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
    // deal with inputs[index] element.
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="name" id="name">
<input type="hidden" name="address" id="address">
<input type="hidden" name="age" id="age">
<input type="hidden" name="sex" id="sex">
```

And then i want to print/console.log:

```
data.name
data.address
data.age
data.sex
```

in that output, i want to add the text "data." and insert the id. How will i do that? Is it valid to use eval() to it? Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you've tagged `jquery`? You don't appear to be using it at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through jQuery you can do it like below:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="hidden"]').each(function(){ // or $('input').each(function(){
     console.log("data."+$(this).attr('id')); //get id of each input
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="name" id="name">
<input type="hidden" name="address" id="address">
<input type="hidden" name="age" id="age">
<input type="hidden" name="sex" id="sex">
```

Note:- jQuery library need to be added before your `script` code.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get name of inputs as:

```
var dummyName = inputs[index].name; //or create array if required
```

and then to read any data using this dummyName as:

```
data[dummyName];
```

Will change answer if any more info is required.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var inputs, index;

var inoutnames = $("input").map(function(){

return "data."+$(this).attr('name')
}).get();

console.log(inoutnames)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="name" id="name">
<input type="hidden" name="address" id="address">
<input type="hidden" name="age" id="age">
<input type="hidden" name="sex" id="sex">
```

1. Use `.map()`
2. Return input attribute name plus "data"

Answer (score 1):

Using pure Javascript, loop over the inputs and store them in an object.

```js
var inputs, index;
var data = {};
inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; index++) {
     data[inputs[index].id] =  inputs[index].value; 
}

console.log(data);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="name" id="name">
<input type="hidden" name="address" id="address">
<input type="hidden" name="age" id="age">
<input type="hidden" name="sex" id="sex">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var inputs, index;
var result=""
inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
  result+= "Name:" + inputs[index].name + ' ' +"Id:"+ inputs[index].id + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=result
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="name" id="name">
<input type="hidden" name="address" id="address">
<input type="hidden" name="age" id="age">
<input type="hidden" name="sex" id="sex">

<div id="demo">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[**`Array#reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce?v=control#Description) could be used to get the object of all the input fields.

> The `reduce()` method applies a function against an accumulator and each element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single value.

```js
var obj = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input')).reduce(function(a, b) {
  a[b.id] = b.value;
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="name" id="name" value="Rayon">
<input type="hidden" name="address" id="address" value="India">
<input type="hidden" name="age" id="age" value="27">
<input type="hidden" name="sex" id="sex" value="M">
```